# How to match a string after a character when the line begins with one of two values?

Tags: regex, perl5.8

I have a text file that's in the following format:

```
# Email File
# List of email addresses
##############################
PRIMARY_EMAIL=abc@123.com
ALTERNATE_EMAIL=123@abc.com
#PRIMARY_EMAIL=def@456.com
#ALTERNATE_EMAIL=456@def.com
PRIMARY_EMAIL=ghi@789.com
ALTERNATE_EMAIL=789@ghi.com
```

This file contains the primary and alternate email addresses for employees. I'm using the file as input for a script I'm using to send a notification to the employees. Some of the email addresses are commented out if the employee is on leave and need to not be included in the results.

The problem I'm having is that I'm unable to match the email address after the "=" sign when the string begins with "PRIMARY_EMAIL" or "ALTERNATE_EMAIL".

Using the following code, I can obtain "PRIMARY_EMAIL", but it doesn't pick up "ALTERNATE_EMAIL". The code below works if I grab the input with two variables and specifically indicate "PRIMARY_EMAIL" or "ALTERNATE_EMAIL" in the regular expression, but I'd like to get everything at once in a single line of code if it's possible.

```perl
while (<$in_file>) {
    $line = $1 if (/^PRIMARY_EMAIL=(.*)|^ALTERNATE_EMAIL=(.*)/);
    chomp;
    if (defined $line) {
        push (@recipient, $line);
    }
}

$to = join("\n", @recipient);
print "\$to = \n", $to, "\n";
```

Output:

```
$to =
abc@123.com
ghi@789.com
```

As you can see, the output/regular expression is not including the values after "ALTERNATE_EMAIL".

The output should be:

```
$to = 
abc@123.com
123@abc.com
ghi@789.com
789@ghi.com
```

I've searched all over for a way to use alternation to match two different strings at the beginning of a line while only returning the potion after the "=" sign, but every example/explanation I've found only deals with a single match at the beginning of a string.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
my @recipient  = (join("", <DATA>) =~ /^(?:PRIMARY_EMAIL|ALTERNATE_EMAIL)=(.*)/mg);
my $to = join("\n", @recipient);
print "\$to = \n", $to, "\n";

__DATA__
# Email File
# List of email addresses
##############################
PRIMARY_EMAIL=abc@123.com
ALTERNATE_EMAIL=123@abc.com
#PRIMARY_EMAIL=def@456.com
#ALTERNATE_EMAIL=456@def.com
PRIMARY_EMAIL=ghi@789.com
ALTERNATE_EMAIL=789@ghi.com
```

`join("", <DATA>)` this is reading all the lines and joining into one. Then using regex I am parsing the emails into the array directly.

Comment: I'm using Perl 5.8 and branch reset isn't available until Perl 5.10. Is there another way to achieve the same results without using branch reset?

Comment: @user2063351 you have placed wrong comment on wrong post! I didn't mention anything about branch resetting!

Comment: I apologize...I thought the `(?:` portion of your regex was a branch reset. I mistook the colon for a bar.

Comment: `?:` means ignore capturing in group from the matching.

Answer (score 0):

Use branch reset `/^(?|PRIMARY_EMAIL=(.*)|ALTERNATE_EMAIL=(.*))/`

```
      ^
      (?|
           PRIMARY_EMAIL=
 br 1      ( .* )                        # (1)
        |  ALTERNATE_EMAIL=
 br 1      ( .* )                        # (1)
      )
```

Or, just this `/^(?:PRIMARY_EMAIL|ALTERNATE_EMAIL)=(.*)/`

```
 ^ 
 (?: PRIMARY_EMAIL | ALTERNATE_EMAIL )
 =
 ( .* )                             # (1)
```

**test case**

```
 while (<DATA>) {
     if (/^(?:PRIMARY_EMAIL|ALTERNATE_EMAIL)=(.*)/)
     {
        push (@recipient, $1);
     }
 }

 $to = join("\n", @recipient);
 print "\$to = \n", $to, "\n";

__DATA__
# Email File
# List of email addresses
##############################
PRIMARY_EMAIL=abc@123.com
ALTERNATE_EMAIL=123@abc.com
#PRIMARY_EMAIL=def@456.com
#ALTERNATE_EMAIL=456@def.com
PRIMARY_EMAIL=ghi@789.com
ALTERNATE_EMAIL=789@ghi.com
```

Output >>

```
 $to =
 abc@123.com
 123@abc.com
 ghi@789.com
 789@ghi.com
```

Here is another way

```
$/ = undef;
print join("\n",(<DATA> =~ /^(?:PRIMARY_EMAIL|ALTERNATE_EMAIL)=(.*)/mg));

__DATA__
# Email File
# List of email addresses
##############################
PRIMARY_EMAIL=abc@123.com
ALTERNATE_EMAIL=123@abc.com
#PRIMARY_EMAIL=def@456.com
#ALTERNATE_EMAIL=456@def.com
PRIMARY_EMAIL=ghi@789.com
ALTERNATE_EMAIL=789@ghi.com
```

Output >>

```
abc@123.com
123@abc.com
ghi@789.com
789@ghi.com
```

Comment: Neither one of these work.

Option 1 causes the following error: "Sequence (?|...) not recognized in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/^(?| <-- HERE PRIMARY_EMAIL(.*)|ALTERNATE_EMAIL(.*))/".

Option 2 has output, but it's not the output I'm looking for. The output is: $to = abc@123.com 123@abc.com ghi@789.com 789@ghi.com 789@ghi.com 789@ghi.com. It appears as though the output is repeating for the elements that are commented out.

Comment: @user2063351 - Check if `branch reset` is available in Perl 5.8, might have only started with 5.10. As for option 2, the output is correct, you're input is `ALTERNATE_EMAIL=789@ghi.com` for the last line.

Comment: @user2063351 - I see, $line in your code is still defined from before when you hit the commented lines that don't match. Change your code slightly, I added an example.

Comment: The original code was compensating for a bad regex. When the regex changed, the code needed change.

Comment: The branch reset operator isn't available until Perl 5.10, so it won't work for me. The error message I provided in the first comment is the error indicating that branch reset isn't recognized. Is there a way to do the same thing without branch reset?